# Dynamic Hexadecimal escape sequence

Tags: javascript

I'm converting a json to HEX and I want to concatenate with a \x

Example:
I have this ->

```
var myString = '"131';
```

And I want this ->

```
var HardCodeString = "\x22\x31\x33\x31" // console.log prints -> "131
```

When I make that string literal, it creates the four-byte string `"131`.

But when I create a loop to create this string out of dynamically-chosen hex values, like so

```
function ascii_to_hexa(str) {

    var arr1 = [];
    for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n ++) {
        var hex = "\\x" + Number(str.charCodeAt(n)).toString(16);
        arr1.push(hex);
    }
    return arr1.join('');
}

var newString = ascii_to_hexa('"131');
```

Look like work, but not!

If I add a console log to newString I can see:

```
'\x22\x31\x33\x31'
```

And if try to validate as the same happens

```
// should be equal, but not
if(HardCodeString == newString) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Is `'\x22\x31\x33\x31'` not what you expected?

Comment: `"\\x"+"some text".split('').map(s=>s.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).join('\\x')`

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I'm feeling the result is not the same when I create a string with the harcode vale and when I try to get by a loop and concatenate with \x

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem (with the expected output)

Comment: _"I'm feeling..."_ is never the right measure for the correctness of code

Comment: How is what you see in the console not what you expect?  It looks identical.

Comment: @Andreas I think the OP has done this, or at least almost -- the question is fairly clear to me (though it's always possible I am misunderstanding as well). The central thing missing is that `var string = "\x22\x31\x33\x31"` initializes a string containing the four-byte sequence `"131`, and this four-byte sequence is really what the OP wants, not the literal 16-byte sequence `\x22\x31\x33\x31`. The question here asks how to make a string by specifying a byte sequence as hex, but do it dynamically instead of via string literal.

Comment: can u tell me what result u expect when `var str = 'abc';`

Comment: @apsillers `var mystring = "\\x" + myString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);` suggests that there's a loop `.charCodeAt(i)`, but then `var mystring = ...` doesn't make much sense, especially not when it's (slightly stripped version) `var mystring = myString.charCodeAt(i)`. For me this is not a complete and verifiable example, nor is there an explanation why TO thinks the script doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @LaionCamargo I clarified your question to fit my understanding of your desired output. (It seemed clear enough to me that if `\x22...` is not the literal output you wanted in the last step, then you must want that string as it would be interpreted a string literal.) If my interpretation is incorrect, please edit your question further to clarify your intent.

Comment: IMO the last edit was destructive and contains code that the OP did not write and that does not work.  I believe it should be reverted.

Comment: @Andreas Having looked at it again, I agree the first line solidly messes up my interpretation (the `"some text"` bit in the original version), and I can't make any sense of the question, viewed as a whole. I've voted to close.

Comment: @LaionCamargo 0x22 is ok for u or u want \x22 ?

Comment: @shajji need to be \x22

Comment: @LaionCamargo can u please describe why u can't use 0x22, even both has same meaning.

Comment: because u can't use concatenation like this `'\x' + 22`, but you can use  concatenate 
like this `'0x' + '22'` and u can get back its char to, by using String.fromCharCode like this `String.fromCharCode("0x41", "0x42");`

Comment: @shajji because I'm using this lib > https://github.com/floodyberry/ed25519-donna and I dont wanna change the original Lib.
This lib just work when I send in hex value like var myString = "\x22\x31\x33...";

Comment: @apsillers whats happen is: if I create my var with this value: var myValue = "\x22\x31\x33\x31"; and create a var with a loop from my string '"131' using var mystring = "\\x" + myString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16); and than make a if(myValue == mystring) its false, because one is a hex  value (myValue) and other just a simple string(mystring)

Comment: Dude @LaionCamargo i only understand one way to do what u want but it is not that good, you can first create js object like this `var hex = { 'A': '\x41', 'B': '\x42' ...};` and replace each char by its hex value. `var val = 'A'; var res = hex[val[0]];`

Comment: if u want detail version of above way using loop, please ask :)

Comment: @shajji I add more information about the code. I belive will be easier to understand

Comment: @shajji for now I converted to 0x and use C++ to transform into a char.

Comment: I give an example in answere section, hopefully that will help u.

Comment: u can use js method `String.fromCharCode("0x31")` to convert its char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this example help u

```
var hex = {
            "\"": '\x22',
            "{": '\x7B',
            "}": '\x7D',
            "A": '\x41',
            "B": '\x42',
            "C": '\x43',
            "D": '\x44',
            "0": '\x30',
            "1": '\x31',
            "3": '\x32',
            "2": '\x33'
        };

        function str_to_hex(str) {
            var res = '';
            for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n++) {
                res += hex[str[n]];
            }
            return res;
        }
        var str = '\"131';
        var res = str_to_hex(str);
        console.log(res);
```

Please ask if any query.